# Second derivative

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I have this functional on $H^1_0$ defined by

$J(u)=\frac12||u||^2-\int_0^1 F(t,u(t)) dt $ where $F(t,u(t))=\int_0^u f(t,s) ds $

and i have  $J'(u)h= \int_0^1u'(t)h'(t) dt - \int_0^1f(t,u(t)) h(t) dt $

How to do to find  $J''(u)(h,k)$ ??

Thank you